# How to get the screen shot of invisible part in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios6

I am working on iOS application where I need to capture the view and send MMS to particular person.Its all working fine.But I am facing problem to capture which is not visible (For more clarification I attached image).

[image]

I am getting the screen shot of the view which is visible.How to solve the problem? Is there any approach to reach my requirement? The image what I am getting is

[image]

I used the code to take screenshot is

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webview_pdf.bounds.size);
[webview_pdf.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *pdfImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Good suggestions are appreciable.Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution to this

```
+ (UIImage *) imageFromWebView:(UIWebView *)view
{
    // tempframe to reset view size after image was created
    CGRect tmpFrame = view.frame;

    // set new Frame
    CGRect aFrame = view.frame;
    aFrame.size.height = [view sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size].height;
    view.frame = aFrame;

    // do image magic
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([view sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size]);

    CGContextRef resizedContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [view.layer renderInContext:resizedContext];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // reset Frame of view to origin
    view.frame = tmpFrame;
    return image;
}
```

Comment: When answering questions with code can you please make sure that the code is formatted correctly as it makes it a lot hard to read if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another view that is the full size of the content. You can add this view off screen and then capture it the same way as you have done here. The reason it is cut off is because the view has only rendered that part of the content.

Comment: But I have a doubt..Does it works if there are unlimited records? @CW0007007

Comment: It may take a long time to create the view. BUt it will work with any size content. Just create another view container off screen. Set the height to the height of your content. Then save that view as n image.

Comment: and more more question for U @CW0007007..The maximum limit of mms is 300kb.As the records increases the image size also increases.Then MMS could not be sent.Then what will be the solution for this?

Comment: Send it in an email. MMS really isn't supposed to be used for sending anything other than small videos and photos …